# How to set the RKEntityMapping.identificationAttributes in RestKit case-insensitive?

Tags: core-data, restkit, case-insensitive

The given identificationAttributes may in different cases in local and server. Can I set the identificationAttributes case-insensitive in order to update data immediately.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't really unique identification attributes if they aren't unique or don't match, so ideally you should correct the server.

Changing the caching system, while possible by subclassing, isn't trivial. So, I'd look at using key paths to run `uppercaseString` on the value in your identification attribute during mapping.